# InflateException thrown when setting id on a FloatingActionButton

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, material-design, inflate-exception

I have a floating action button control added to my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/main_fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_fab_margin"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_main_fab"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/color_primary"
            app:elevation="@dimen/main_fab_elevation"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Pull-out navigation drawer (a.k.a hamburger menu) -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigationmenu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawerheader" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This throws an InflateException that looks like:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView
```

The floating action button is a child of a RelativeLayout which a child of a android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.

Now the weird part, when I remove

```
android:id="@+id/main_fab"
```

from the above code, everything works perfectly.

I have no idea what could be causing this.  I really need to set an id to the button so I can control the clicks in the code-behind.

Any ideas?

**Update**

Stack trace:

```
Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView

08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025): Process: RA16mobile.RA16mobile, PID: 16025
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NormalViewHolder.<init>(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:278)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:379)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:328)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1211)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16646)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5440)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2183)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1943)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
08-04 16:49:39.952 E/AndroidRuntime(16025):     at android.view.Choreograp
08-04 16:49:40.000 I/Process (16025): Sending signal. PID: 16025 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you show the complete xml?

Comment: It's odd that you get that Exception from attributes on the `FloatingActionButton`. What's your `Activity` superclass? You should be using `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: the main activity does inherit from AppCompatActivity, not Activity.  Full XML posted.

Comment: Hmm for me the exception points more to `@menu/navigationmenu`

Comment: I agree, that's the way it appears, but the code runs perfectly fine until you give the floating action button an id.  That's what leads me to believe that the FAB is the issue.  It wouldn't make sense for the navigation menu to be the problem when removing one line in the FAB removes the problem altogether.

Comment: Try to nuke your obj/bin folders, Restart your IDE, and do a clean deploy. (i.e. `adb uninstall packagename`). I've seen this issue quite frequently with regards to `Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView` and it seems to fix it.

Comment: @JonDouglas this worked!  Thanks a lot for the help.  Please write this up in an answer so I close this and give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to nuke your `obj/bin` folders, Restart your IDE, and do a clean deploy. (i.e. `adb uninstall packagename`). I've seen this issue quite frequently with regards to `Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView` and it seems to fix it.

I thought originally this was a Xamarin specific error until I've encountered it in Native Java as well. Basically following the same steps resolves the issues in both lands.